# How to properly call startActivityForResult() from a viewHolder onClickListener?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am trying to implement RecyclerView in a small project and ran into some problem. My adapter works fine for adding new elements, but doesn't do anything when I edit existing ones.

For creating a new element I use FloatingActionButton in my fragment and send an appropiate request code. For editing an element I tried implementing onClickListener() in onBindViewHolder(). Here's the code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.EventViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Event event = mEvents.get(position);
    holder.mLabel.setText(event.getLabel());
    holder.mComment.setText(event.getComment());
    holder.mStartTime.setText(DateFormat.format("HH:mm", event.getTime()));
    holder.mDuration.setText(event.getDurationInFormat(mContext));
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), EventCreatorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EX_EVENT_ID, event.getId());
            intent.putExtra(EX_DAY_ID, event.getParent().getId());
            ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, DayViewFragment.RC_EDIT);
        }
    });
}
```

(itemView is where I keep the entire element view, and the Textviews are just components).

Here's where I initialize the RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Restore data after app-configuration
        if(savedInstanceState != null && !savedInstanceState.isEmpty())
            mDay = Day.findDayById(UUID.fromString(savedInstanceState.getString(DAY_ID)));
        else
            mDay = new Day(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Event>());
        adapter.updateDataSet(mDay.getEvents());

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And here's where I recieve the results in the fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
            return;

        UUID eventId = (UUID)data.getSerializableExtra(EventCreatorFragment.EX_EVENT_ID);
        Event event = mDay.findEventById(eventId);

        switch (requestCode){
            case RC_EDIT:{
                int previousPosition = adapter.getPreviousPosition(eventId);
                if(previousPosition == mDay.getIndex(event))
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(mDay.getIndex(event));
                else {
                    adapter.updateDataSet(mDay.getEvents());
                    adapter.notifyItemMoved(previousPosition, mDay.getIndex(event));
                }
            } break;
            case RC_ADD:{
                adapter.updateDataSet(mDay.getEvents());
                adapter.notifyItemInserted(mDay.getIndex(event));
            } break;
        }
    }
```

Here's where I set the result, in the fragment of the activity which creates\edits new elements:

```
public void sendResult(){
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(EX_EVENT_ID, mThisEvent.getId());
    getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
}
```

A few things worth noting:

1. As I said, adding new elements work just fine.
2. When an element is clicked, it sends for the EvenetCreatorActivity just fine, and there it shows the data has been edited successfuly (The various values change).
3. I traced through the code, and onActivityResult() isn't called at all after editing an element.
4. I've read online that it's possible that the activity that's supposed to get the results is destroyed for some reason, but it isn't the case.

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: You will receive at onActivityResult at Fragment only if you used the fragment context for startActivityForResult but you are using Activity... the onActivityResult will get back to the Activity that is the context from the adapter

Comment: Wow... Well. I thought the fragment overriding onActicityResult will automatically be directed to by its activity calling startActivityForResult(). It didn't even occur to me that it matters. Need to be a bit more reading I guess. Thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 2):

You will receive at onActivityResult at Fragment only if you used the fragment context for startActivityForResult but you are using Activity... the onActivityResult will get back to the Activity that is the context from the adapter.